# Zip is corrupted, unpacks on Mac but not on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a zip file that is indeed corrupted. It contains one file that is fine, and a second that is 0bytes and corrupted. But when I unpack it on my Mac (double click in finder), it does unpack and I'm able to see the files.

When I try to unzip it using the command line in Ubuntu, I get a

```
zip@zip-test ~]# unzip test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of test.zip or
        test.zip.zip, and cannot find test.zip.ZIP, period.
```

I've also tried:

```
[zip@zip-test ~]# jar xvf test.zip
 inflated: data-2014-07-25-08-55-10.gps
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:163)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:109)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:954)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:870)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:260)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1167)
```

And lastly I've tried

```
[zip@zip-test ~]# 7za x test.zip

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)

Processing archive: test.zip

Error: Can not open file as archive
```

But since I can unzip it on the Mac, it seems like there should be some way to force the package to unzip. Any ideas on what else to try?

EDIT: you can find the file here: http://cl.ly/1n3G0z3q3G3u

Comment: It would likely help to post a copy of the zip - did you make the zip on a Mac as well, or download it from somewhere?

Comment: The zip was made by an iOS app. You can find it here:
http://cl.ly/1n3G0z3q3G3u